# How can i interact with views while they keep animating in UIKit (swift 4)?

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation, user-interaction

I have a set of shapes (`UIView`s), that can be moved on the screen using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, and that are supposed to wiggle continuously and forever after the user triggers the animation. But I want them to keep wiggling, even while the user picks one up and moves it.
What is practically happening is that when the user picks up a shape, it stops animating, and when he puts it back down, it doesn't even restart the animation.

Here's some code for the context:

```
func wiggle() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animation: {
        self.view.subviews.forEach { $0.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/8) })
}

func pickUpShape() {
     [.....]
     shape.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, scaleY: 2)
     shape.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
}

func moveShape() {
    //apply UIPanGestureRecognizer
}

func placeShape() {
    [.....]
    shape.transform = .identity
    shape.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
}
```

What I want it to do is, if the user triggers the wiggle action, and picks a shape up and moves it, i want the shape to continue wiggling under the user's finger, and after he places it down.

Comment: The `shape.transform = .identity` line looks suspect. Is calling this necessary?

Comment: @Leo Yes, cz after the user picks up the object, it grows, ans when he puts it back down, it should get to it’s original form. Anw i don’t think it has anything to do with this function, cz if they’re wiggling, as soon as “pickUpShape()” gets called, the shaped that has been picked up stops wiggling.

Comment: It was my assumption that setting the shape back to `.identity` would stop the CAAffineTransformation animation.

Comment: I removed it, but that didn't fix the problem